# Has the human race ever done Antimatter experiments in outer space (e.g. on the ISS)?

Tags: antimatter

If not, what is the roadmap for the first Antimatter experiment in outer space?

Comment: I think the first step on the roadmap would be to explain what the purpose of experimenting with antimatter in orbit would be. What kind of experiment?  You would need a compelling reason why you'd expect different results for this experiment in orbit compared to the ground - it's very expensive to put things to orbit!

Comment: One advantage of outer space is weightlessness, which probably makes storing antimatter easier. You would still have to overcome the pressure of the antimatter gas. We have already made antihydrogen and if that is cold enough, it might form a solid with low or no vapor pressure. But creating AM usually requires particle accelerators which are usually rather heavy and bulky, which is difficult to get to space. There is also a very good vacuum in outer space, better than can be achieved on Earth, which helps accelerate particles and avoid collisions with the antimatter.

Comment: Weightlessness only removes a force on (anti)hydrogen atoms of $10^{-25}N$.  Since thermal motion has to be prevented anyway for containment, it doesn't seem to be a big benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer) is an experiment aboard the ISS that studies antimatter in cosmic rays.

However I'm guessing you're asking if we have made antimatter then bottled it up and studied it's properties on the ISS. If that is your question then the answer is no, and it doesn't seem likely an experiment like that would be worth doing. In most cases the lifetime of antimatter particles is exceedingly short, because they rapidly encounter normal matter and annihilate. The timescales are usually too short for gravity to have any significant effect on the matter. In fact, the effect of gravity on antimatter has still not been precisely measured.

So give that gravity has little effect on the behaviour of antimatter here on Earth, it doesn't seem likely that removing gravity by doing experiments on the ISS would tell us anything new.

Comment: "the timescales are usually too short for gravity to have any significant effect" ..is this not a good argument to "bottled it up" ? I mean really if there is one thing what we have in space then it is space. So why not build a huge linear vacuum accelerator in space?

Comment: @RandyWelt: Cost. If we had that sort of money available we'd use it to build the same linear accelerator much more cheaply on Earth.

Comment: @ John Rennie, why do you believe in Cost? Prices are just imaginary regulators. It just works as long people believe in it. I don't.

Comment: You're not a tax payer, are you?

Comment: student, who believes in a fully automated economy. :)